# 組込LinuxシステムでLANを接続すると時計がずれる

Tags: linux

YOCTOを使用し、組み込みLinuxシステムを構築しています。

LAN接続を接続すると時計がずれるという問題が発生し、この対応に苦労しています。
"内蔵時計がずれる"というのは、システムがUTCベースで動いており、これが日本時間に強制変更される為です。

発生する要因として、２つあります。
①LAN上にNTPサーバーが見つかり、NTPで内蔵時計(RTC)をあわしに行ってしまう。この時は内臓のRTCも変更されてしまう。
②DHCPサーバーがあると、サーバーの時刻にあわせてしまう。こちらはRTCの変更は行われない。

①の場合、通常、ntpのクライアントデーモンが動作していると思いますが、起動しているデーモンの中にそれらしき物が見つかりません。
（ `ps ax | grep ntp` で引っかからない ）
YOCTOでは、どのソフトが行っているのでしょうか？
また、これを停止するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
こちらは、最悪、NTPサーバーを見つからなくするため、avahiを止めることを考えています。

②も同様に、`ps ax | grep dhcp` で引っかからず、どのソフトがdhcpのクライアントか判りません。
同じように、どのソフトが行っているのでしょうか？
そして、これを止めるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

以下は、ps axの内容です。

```
root@***********:~# ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:01 init [5]
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    4 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:0]
    5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
    6 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u4:0]
    7 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_preempt]
    9 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_sched]
   11 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
   13 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:0]
   14 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
   15 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   17 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
   18 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:1]
   19 ?        S<     0:00 [writeback]
   20 ?        S<     0:00 [bioset]
   21 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
   22 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
   23 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
   24 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u4:1]
   35 ?        S      0:00 [ipu1_task]
   36 ?        S      0:00 [ipu1_task]
   37 ?        S      0:00 [ipu2_task]
   38 ?        S      0:00 [ipu2_task]
   39 ?        S<     0:00 [cfg80211]
   40 ?        S<     0:00 [rpciod]
   41 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
   42 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
   43 ?        S<     0:00 [nfsiod]
   44 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   80 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
   81 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
   82 ?        S      0:00 [spi32766]
   83 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u4:2]
   86 ?        S      0:00 [spi32765]
   89 ?        S      0:00 [ci otg thread]
   90 ?        S      0:00 [irq/352-2190000]
   91 ?        S      0:00 [irq/353-2198000]
   92 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/1]
   93 ?        S<     0:00 [galcore workque]
   94 ?        S      0:00 [Vivante Kernel ]
   95 ?        S      0:00 [galcore daemon ]
   96 ?        S      0:00 [galcore daemon ]
   97 ?        S      0:00 [galcore daemon ]
   98 ?        S<     0:00 [vpu_wq]
   99 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/2]
  100 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/2boot0]
  101 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/2boot1]
  102 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/2rpmb]
  145 ?        S<     0:00 [krfcommd]
  146 ?        S<     0:00 [deferwq]
  147 ?        S      0:00 [kinteractiveup]
  148 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
  149 ?        S      0:00 [kjournald]
  176 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/udev/udevd -d
  208 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
  573 ?        S      0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk1p1-]
  575 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  633 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/rpcbind
  649 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc5.d/S01xserver-nodm start background
  672 ?        S      0:00 xinit /etc/X11/Xsession -- /usr/bin/Xorg -br -pn -noc
  673 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
  675 ?        S<s    0:01 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -pn -nocursor
  677 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/connmand
  682 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host
  702 ?        S      0:00 /lib/udev/udevd -d
  704 ?        S      0:00 /lib/udev/udevd -d
  712 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/syslogd -n -O /var/log/messages
  715 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/klogd -n
  721 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [***********.local]
  722 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  733 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/ofonod
  738 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/oprofile-server
  743 ?        S      0:00 autohdmi
  754 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/rc_mxc.S
  755 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
  758 ttymxc1  Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -L ttymxc1 115200 vt100
  760 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /etc/matchbox/session
  764 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --auto-syntax --exit-with-sessio
  765 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-add
  783 ?        S      0:00 connman-applet
  803 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/gconf/gconfd-2
  814 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/settings-daemon
  854 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host
  855 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -sh
  856 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 組み込み機器のタイムゾーン設定や、RTC にローカル/UTCのどちらを記録するかの設定がずれていたりしませんか？ 後者は Yocto だと`/etc/default/rcS` あたりですかね。NTP は UTC でのタイムスタンプしか扱わないので、設定の間違えている NTP サーバを使わない限り時刻がずれることはないはずです。 (そのようなNTP サーバがあると、それを利用した他の機器も時刻がずれるので分かると思います)

Comment: avahiを停止しNTPが動作しないようにして、"/etc/default/rcS" の "UTC=yes" を "UTC=no"にしても日本時間に変わってしまいます。WireSharkでモニタしてもNTPは発生していません。モニタで見る限り、怪しいのはDHCPのパケットだけだと思いました。

Comment: あまり関係ないかもしれませんが、ipv6を止めてもダメでした。dhcp関連のポート67、68を禁止できないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できましたので、結果を報告させて頂きます。
●DHCPの時間合わせは、カーネル組み込みでした。
●menuconfigで以下の設定を切り、対応できました。
    -> Networking support (NET [=y])
    -> Networking options
    -> TCP/IP networking (INET [=y])
    [*]   IP: kernel level autoconfiguration

    [*]     IP: DHCP support

```
-> Networking support (NET [=y])
-> Networking options
<*> Packet socket
```

Packet Socketも切らないとダメでした。